# MDPDF: Markdown to PDF conversion with dynamic footer or header

Tags: javascript, html, macos, markdown, pdf-generation

I'm trying to do a markdown to PDF conversion with [mdpdf](https://github.com/BlueHatbRit/mdpdf) on macOS.

The basic PDF creation works.

My problem is to **add a footer (or header) with dynamic content**, in this case, a date.

Here's my `test.md`:

```
# An MDPDF Test
- convert markdown (.md) to PDF

https://github.com/BlueHatbRit/mdpdf/blob/master/examples/footers/md-file.md
```

Here's my `test_footer.html`:

```
<script>
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleDateString();
</script>

<center style="font-size: 10px">
    <p>FOOTER with locale date: <span id="datetime"></span></p>
</center>
```

Then I call in Terminal:

```
mdpdf /Users/felix/test.md  --footer=/Users/felix/test_footer.html
```

As a result I get a PDF file with the footer *text* placed in lower left, but the actual date in the upper left corner and without localisation.

**How to get the date into the footer?**

Here are some things I tried:

- If I delete all code in `test_footer.html` and run again, there is still a date in the upper left corner.
- If I run `mdpdf /Users/felix/test.md` (without --footer option), there's no date at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution to my question.
It seems mdfpdf is using [Pupeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v1.11.0/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) to inject header and footer.
There's a `date` class.

My `test_footer.html` now looks like this:

```
<center style="font-size: 10px">
    <p>FOOTER with locale date: <span class="date"></span></p>
</center>
```

The footer is displayed on the lower **left**, with generic (not localized) date. Better already ... but the date also shows up in the upper left.

I created an empty `test_header.html` file and call:

```
mdpdf /Users/felix/test.md  --header=/Users/felix/test_header.html --footer=/Users/felix/test_footer.html
```

The header is now empty, but footer still in lower left, not center...